# How to change keyboard orientation in ios6

Tags: iphone, ipad, keyboard, ios6

I have a problem. I am developing a game like ludo. In this i have to create text field, for all players participating in game. These players may be in all directions of iPad. And for filling answer in this text field user can use keyboard of iPad. But problem is that I am unable to open keyboard form all sides of iPad.

I am using-

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarOrientation:toInterfaceOrientation animated:YES];
```

for changing orientation of keyboard. It is working in lower ios versions. But in ios6 it is not working properly. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Have you written orientation methods for ios 6? and have you allow your all orientation in .info plist file?

If not then it is here write down..

```
-(BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
   return YES;
}
-(NSInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
   return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll;
}
```

Then try to orient your device and let me know is it working or not...!

Happy coding!

Comment: This is not true dear, i think if you will return Yes in -(BOOL)shouldAutorotate method. Then status bar orientation will not work

Answer (score 0):

Never return YES always in

```
-(BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
   return YES;
}
```

In AppDelegate write code

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:YES forKey:@"_rotation"];
```

And change above method like this

```
-(BOOL)shouldAutorotate
 {
    return [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"_rotation"];
 }
```

Now where you want to change orientation in application. Set above flag for _rotation to NO and after calling method of statusBarOrientation again set this to YES.
This is because statusBarOrientation method will work only if shouldAutorotate method will return NO.

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:NO forKey:@"_rotation"];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarOrientation:toInterfaceOrientation animated:YES];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:YES forKey:@"_rotation"];
```